# mod_rewrite ignores [L]

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to be able to rewrite this

```
http://localhost/.../identicon/f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6.png
```

to

```
http://localhost/.../identicon.php?hash=f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6
```

so I add to the /.../.htaccess so this is it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^resource/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^identicon/(.+)\.png$ identicon.php?hash=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?t=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which doesn't work for some reason because it redirects it to index.php?t=identicon.php; even though the L flag is set!  Why?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: @Matchu added now, it redirects to index.php instead of identicon.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition to the last rule to exclude requests that can be mapped to existing files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?t=$1 [QSA,L]
```

That is necessary because the [*L* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) generates an internal redirect with the new URL as the request URL:

> Remember, however, that if the `RewriteRule` generates an internal redirect (which frequently occurs when rewriting in a per-directory context), this will reinject the request and will cause processing to be repeated starting from the first `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 0):

*(Not correct answer; left for reference)*

---

I just figured out what may be the issue - it's something that thwarted me for a long time.

Depending on your server settings, it very well may be interpreting `identicon/xxx.png` as a request to `identicon.php/xxx.png`, assuming that the PHP extension is what you wanted. Try going to `/index` instead of `/index.php` - if it loads the PHP file, this is the issue affecting you.

This is the MultiViews Apache option, and it's stupid, but it has to be enabled specifically. Go into your site configuration file and see where it is enabled, and remove it.

If you don't have total control over your server configuration, the following may work in .htaccess (depending, ironically, on your server configuration).

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: I made index.php dump the value of $_GET['t'] to the screen: `index/a.png` prints `index/a.png`, but `identicon/a.php` just dumps `identicon.php`.  Also, I tried changing "identicon" in the RewriteRule to something else and it still failed.

Comment: And no, MultiViews isn't enabled.